# What set which involves building a dump truck has the most pieces?

Tags: set-identification, sets

I'm trying to recall a bricks set I used more than a decade ago which I remember needing an inordinate amount of pieces to build a dump truck or similar piece of construction equipment. I haven't been able to find such a set on my own so hopefully I can get some help here. Frankly, I'm not sure if it's even a LEGO set or different brand.

While don't remember much about it, it's still important to create a post that has a definitive answer so I'll settle for identifying which LEGO set has the most pieces and involves building a dump truck.

Comment: That is pretty much a description of any dump truck LEGO has ever made. What were the colors? Number of axles? What size it was? Was it Technic or System? Any specific features (like text or images on stickers) were present?

Comment: I'm trying to cast a wide net. "Any" number of features/ colors/ or other identifying information. The only requirement it that the set involves a dump truck

Comment: Slightly tongue in cheek, so not an answer, but the "LEGO set <that> has the most pieces and involves building a dump truck" must be [42055 - Bucket Wheel Excavator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42055-1), even though the dump truck accounts for only a small fraction of the almost 4000 parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few candidates.

At minifig scale we've got [4202-1 "Mining Truck"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4202-1) modeled after a [haul truck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haul_truck), with 264 parts:

[image: Set 4202-1]

On the Technic side, there's [42114-1 "6x6 Volvo Articulated Trailer"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42114-1) with 2193 parts (as pointed out by @MatthewJensen):

[image: Set 42114-1]

But if your criteria is "*a set which involves a dump truck*", then the answer (for minifig scale) is probably [60188-1 "Mining Experts Site"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60188-1) with 857 parts, albeit with a rather simplistic truck...

[image: Set 60188-1]

Or, as user @SanderDeDycker points out, technic [set 42055-1 "Bucket Wheel Excavator"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42055-1) with 3929 parts and a relatively tiny dumper:

[image: Set 42055]

Looking at the [list of construction sets ordered by descending number of parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=67.518.596&catType=S&v=1) did help in choosing these.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for! Thank you! I'll wait a short while before marking it as accepted

Comment: Your edit with the Mining Truck is the set I've been looking for! I don't think I was able to identify in my search because it wasn't explicitly referred to as a dump truck.

Comment: There is also [42114 6x6 Volvo Articulated Hauler](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42114-1)